# Devolver hora TimePicker en OnClick (Android )

Tags: android, android-studio, datetimepicker

Como puedo devolver la hora escogida por el usuario en un TimePicker?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hourD = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

  btnHour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimePickerDialog dialog2 = new TimePickerDialog(
                    Map.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,onTimeSetListener,hourD,minute,boolea);
            dialog2.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog2.show();
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu listener `onTimeSetListener` tiene un método llamado [onTimeSet()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html#onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker,%20int,%20int)), aquí puedes obtener el valor, ejemplo:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener=
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            int hora = hourOfDay;
            int minuto = minute;

        }
    };
```

Comment: Resuelto, muchas gracias!